# Is there any way to make a GitFlow release with only specific commits on the develop branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

Title, I hope, is self explanatory, but here it is:

I have multiple commits to the develop branch and I need only to push some of the to the master branch, by doing a release if possible (that's the way I'd prefer doing it). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have multiple commits to the develop branch and I need only to push some of the to the master branch

You should use `git cherry-pick`

---

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1> <SHA-1> <SHA-1> ...`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit with this change.

You could also specify a range for the cherry-pick

```
git cherry-pick <SHA-1>...<SHA-1>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's a nifty little part of Git that I didn't knew it's existence! That's great. I guess, in a Gitflow workflow, I would then have to create the release, cherry-pick to the release and then finish the release to merge to master? I'll probaby just cherry-pick directly to master and bypass the workflow directly, that might be more productive.

Comment: I dont fully understand your structure.  But the general idea is correct